# Don't execute Worksheet_Calculate event on Workbook_Open

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook.

In one of the worksheets I make use of the `Worksheet_Calculate` event. This works fine. However when the workbook is first opened I do not want `MyFunction` to be called. What is the best away to do this?

My only idea so far is the following (I don't like this though). On the workbook open method put a time stamp in one of the worksheets and then have an if statement in my `worksheet_calculate` and if the current time is 1 minute past the time stamp (that was created on the `workbook_open` event) run the code otherwise don't.

Thinking there must be a better way though?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    MyFunction()
End Sub
```

**Update**

The reason I do not want my code to execute when the workbook opens is because there are some Bloomberg formulas that take a little time to execute so initially some of the cell values are #NA.

This causes a type mismatch error - any errors that happen are logged and an e-mail is automatically sent. So every time the workbook is opened there is an 'error' as the bloomberg formulas have not updated straight away

Comment: Maybe have a public boolean declared on opening, that is set to true at the end of the Workbook_Open method. Have your thing run only when it is true. It could prevent running the first time.

Comment: If your workbook calculates on open, that will occur before any events are run, including the `Open` event. Why don't you want the code to run first off - what does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below should work for you.
The first time calculate is called it sets the flag to allow future calls to process. This means the first call to calculate does not process your code.

ThisWorkbook Code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    bFunctionFlag = False
End Sub
```

Sheet Code:

```
Public bFunctionFlag As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If bFunctionFlag = True Then Call MyFunction
    bFunctionFlag = True
End Sub

Private Function MyFunction()
    MsgBox "Calculate"
End Function
```

Comment: `bFunctionFlag = False` is redundant in Workbook_Open()

Comment: While in essence you may be correct it does not follow good coding practice. Perhaps you should look at the following: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninitialized_variable

Comment: What I was getting at is that by setting 'bFunctionFlag = False' in the workbook open event you are liable to lose the state of bFunctionFlag if the variables reset. If you swap the true/false assignment in the event and sub then you can't lose state.

Answer (score 0):

In the workbook open event you can have

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'Run Workbook Open code
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

or if you need events to run from external services then do something similar with a public variable. Eg `Dim wbOpenEventEnded as Boolean`